# In what number space do brms, lme4 etc. understand priors in a binomial (logit link) model?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, prior

I understand that predictors in a logit-linked binomial linear model are mapped onto the 0..1 probability range by the logit function. A normal distribution that would be considered flat in a `family = gaussian` model, like `normal(0, 5)`, however, when it is mapped by `logit()`, ends up with a strong emphasis on extreme values, close to 0 or 1. My question is: How does `brms` (or probably analogously, `glmer`, `glm` etc.) understand priors provided to binomial (in extension: Poisson & log link) models? Is it as I described, with 1.5 being sort of a "flat" prior?